# Custom Back Button With Image

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

What I'd like to do is alter the height of the back button. However, as I understand it, the only option to alter is width. So, I thought I'd create a custom back button with my own, smaller, image. Now I've done this using the viewDidLoad method with the code below:

```
//Setup navigation bar
        navigationController?.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image:UIImage(named:"back_arrow.png"), style:UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target:nil, action:nil)
        navigationController?.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem!.title = ""
```

However, the back button remains blue, large, and has the title 'Back'. How can I get this code to work properly? The debugger says it is running, but it is not changing anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For color you have to set the tint color on navBar, also you can set `navigationItem.backBarButtonItem` to `nil` and use `leftbarButtonItem` with custom button image.

Comment: Then I lose the stock back functionality of the backBarButton. I just want to change the image of the back bar button, get rid of the title, and retain the back functionality.

Comment: yeah, but you can do that anyway in the left bar button handler [self.navigationController popToRootViewController]

Answer (score 7):

I'm going to show you how to do this in the entire app, not just one page.

**To change the default image of the back button, put the following in your app delegate `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`**:

Swift:

```
let backArrowImage = UIImage(named: "customImage")
let renderedImage = backArrowImage?.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysOriginal)
UINavigationBar.appearance().backIndicatorImage = renderedImage
UINavigationBar.appearance().backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = renderedImage
```

Obj-c:"

```
UIImage *backArrowImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"customImage"];
UIImage *renderedImage = [backArrowImage imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
[UINavigationBar appearance].backIndicatorImage = renderedImage;
[UINavigationBar appearance].backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = renderedImage;
```

**To remove the "Back" text from the button, add this category to your AppDelegate.m file (or your own category)**:

Not sure how to do this in Swift yet, so here's the Obj-c version:

```
@implementation UINavigationItem (LuxeCustomization)

/**
 Removes text from all default back buttons so only the arrow or custom image shows up
 */
-(UIBarButtonItem *)backBarButtonItem
{
    return [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
}

@end
```

Comment: To remove "Back" button title globally in swift... see http://stackoverflow.com/a/33707584/6059628