# How to remove all navigationbar back button title

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem

When I push a `UIViewController`, it has some title in back button at new `UIViewController`, if the title has a lot of text, It does not look good in iPhone 4s So I want to remove it.

If I add some code in `prepareForSegue` function, it is going to be a trouble.

Any better way to achieve this？

Comment: you can also change the title of back button. and to go back you requires back button . so i think no need to remove back button.

Comment: please inform after solving your problem.

Comment: refer this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/48801613/3976183

Comment: there's nice article about this issue
https://sarunw.com/posts/how-to-remove-text-from-uinavigationbar-back-button/?utm_campaign=AppCoda%20Weekly&utm_medium=email&utm_source=Revue%20newsletter

Answer (score 138, accepted):

If you want back arrow so following code put into `AppDelegate` file into `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method.

`For Objective-C`

```
 [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(0, -60) forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

`For Swift`

```
let BarButtonItemAppearance = UIBarButtonItem.appearance()
BarButtonItemAppearance.setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.clear], for: .normal)
```

Another option give below.

In `Objective C`

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
```

In `Swift`

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title:"", style:.plain, target:nil, action:nil)
```

**UPDATE :**

```
    let BarButtonItemAppearance = UIBarButtonItem.appearance()

    let attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey: Any] = [
    BarButtonItemAppearance.setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.clear], for: .normal)
            NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 0.1),
            NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.clear]

    BarButtonItemAppearance.setTitleTextAttributes(attributes, for: .normal)
    BarButtonItemAppearance.setTitleTextAttributes(attributes, for: .highlighted)
```

**UPDATE SWIFT 4.1 :**

```
    let attributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.font:  UIFont(name: "Helvetica-Bold", size: 0.1)!, NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.clear]

    BarButtonItemAppearance.setTitleTextAttributes(attributes, for: .normal)
    BarButtonItemAppearance.setTitleTextAttributes(attributes, for: .highlighted)
```

**Using Offset**

```
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment(UIOffsetMake(-1000, 0), for:UIBarMetrics.default)
```

Comment: `setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment` does not always work, when the back button title is very long, but not long enough to change to "Back", the title in the middle will move right.

Comment: @zgjie it's just a subject of how large your offset. you can easily replace '-60' with '-6000' and forget about this problem

Comment: Just a little precision here, the title belongs to the PREVIOUS view controller. So remember to set it there, before the presentViewController or pushViewController method.

Comment: Hmm, this does doesn't work in AppDelegate. "Value of type AppDelegate has no member navigationItem"

Comment: @Prabhu what are you doing?

Comment: I tried this: self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: nil, action: nil)

Comment: That seems to work. Is it a hack or is that the recommended approach? Thanks.

Comment: @sixl I agree can't found how to set the bar button hidden app wide, so I just  put the adjustment value to -999999

Comment: @Prabhu You should set your navigationItem in your viewController (somewhere like viewDidLoad:) instead of AppDelegate. Then it should work.

Comment: Is there any NON HACKY way to to this? This seems really tricky or really not good way to hide the label to just put the position of the label away... I mean is there some way to set its text to ""??

Comment: @DominikBucher I've made a category for this behaviour which hides back button title from every where in the app which is kinda ["NON HACKY" way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46153030/3308174), just add the category in your project and you're done . I strongly disagree with the solution of setting position using `setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment:forBarMetrics:` if user has enabled button shape from accessibility settings the shape will show up ending up ugly navigation bar.

Comment: setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment will break your vertical alignment in iOS11

Comment: @alasker: I'm facing this issue of broken vertical alignment, do you have any better solution to hide the back title widely ? (I don't wan't to do it in every single viewcontroller of my app).

Comment: No, sorry... in my case I only had to hide it a few times so it wasn't such a problem. I guess someone will come up with something sooner than later.. or you can turn to apple's dev forums for an answer.

Comment: @NimitParekh `setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment ` not working properly in xcode 9. The offset affects not only the back button text but also back arrows position. same code works properly in xcode 8. Have u got any solution to this?

Comment: Seems like a hacky way. You can still see the "Back" text **during** the click on the back button.

Comment: It affects not only back button title but also for example search controller cancel button. So be aware!, it might be better just to set the previous screen title to an empty string.

Answer (score 82):

Work's like charm on Swift 3

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = " "
```

Comment: This is the only one that worked when using `navigationController?.pushViewController(_, animated:)`

Comment: Thanks, mate. This one was the only one that worked out. Cheers.

Comment: Worked for me also Swift 4

Comment: It works. Better write an extension for UIViewController with this line.

Comment: @MaksimKniazev, any fix for that problem? I found the only solution to update the title again in `viewWillAppear:`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45366130/5061249 better solves the problem without any side effect.

Comment: this removes the title of the previous view

Comment: if need to remove the back button title:
`self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backItem?.title = ""`

Comment: downvoting because it removes the title if a large title is enabled.

Answer (score 52):

I'm using this line of code in `AppDelegate` file into `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method to remove the backbutton `title`.

**Swift 2.x**

```
let barAppearace = UIBarButtonItem.appearance()
barAppearace.setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment(UIOffsetMake(0, -60), forBarMetrics:UIBarMetrics.Default)
```

**Swift 3.x**

```
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment(UIOffsetMake(0, -60), for:UIBarMetrics.default)
```

**Swift 4.x**

```
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.clear], for: .normal)
    UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.clear], for: UIControlState.highlighted)
```

Comment: `setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment` does not always work, when the back button title is very long, but not long enough to change to "Back", the title in the middle will move right.

Comment: It's not an ideal solution. If we set any navigation title without change the left navigation bar item's title, the title will shift right because of having left navigation bar title insets.

Comment: in iOS 11 it is break the back button position. It falls below its original position

Comment: How is that supposed to work? The text will still be accessible via VoiceOver.

Comment: This creates problem when cancel or done barbuttonitem are not visible when presenting imagepicker or something

Answer (score 23):

Just need go to your **Parent ViewController** from where your other ViewControllers are dependent.

```
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
super.viewWillDisappear(true)
navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .Plain, target: nil, action: nil)}
```

Answer (score 19):

Just copy this code in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions`

## Swift 5

```
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment(UIOffset(horizontal: -1000.0, vertical: 0.0), for: .default)
```

## Swift 4

```
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment(UIOffsetMake(-1000.0, 0.0), for: .default)
```

Comment: Not working on iOS 15, xCode 13

Answer (score 17):

it is simple. put a space in the title of the back button and ready.
Remember that it has to be in the previous view where you want to remove the text.

[image]

Comment: Best solution IMO. Doesn't require you to set the whole app to a specific clear style which may have the side-affect of making any text barbuttonitems disappear. Answer could be made better if it mentioned that you have to drag a navigationItem to your controller if there isn't one there.

Answer (score 17):

On iOS 14 is now present the `backButtonDisplayMode` property in `UINavigationItem` class. So, to remove back button title you can use

```
navigationItem.backButtonDisplayMode = .minimal
```

in the `viewDidLoad` func of the viewController where you want remove it.

To remove it in all navigationBar I used the swizzling technique

```
import UIKit

private let swizzling: (UIViewController.Type, Selector, Selector) -> Void = { forClass, originalSelector, swizzledSelector in
    if let originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(forClass, originalSelector), let swizzledMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(forClass, swizzledSelector) {
        let didAddMethod = class_addMethod(forClass, originalSelector, method_getImplementation(swizzledMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(swizzledMethod))
        if didAddMethod {
            class_replaceMethod(forClass, swizzledSelector, method_getImplementation(originalMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(originalMethod))
        } else {
            method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swizzledMethod)
        }
    }
}

extension UIViewController {
    
    static func swizzle() {
        let originalSelector1 = #selector(viewDidLoad)
        let swizzledSelector1 = #selector(swizzled_viewDidLoad)
        swizzling(UIViewController.self, originalSelector1, swizzledSelector1)
    }
    
    @objc open func swizzled_viewDidLoad() {
        if let _ = navigationController {
            if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
                navigationItem.backButtonDisplayMode = .minimal
            } else {
                // Fallback on earlier versions
                navigationItem.backButtonTitle = ""
            }
        }
        swizzled_viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

And in `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` call

```
UIViewController.swizzle()
```

Comment: Good to know about .minimal, but you need to set this on the nav controller that pushed the current view controller onto the stack. Unfortunately you can't just set it on the displaying view controller...

Comment: Do I have to call the same method again inside swizzled_viewDidLoad?

Comment: @ohtwo Yes, you have to call it. Swizzling exchanges method implementations, so with  `swizzled_viewDidLoad()` you are calling the original one.

Answer (score 9):

You could create a subclass for all `UIViewController`s you want this behavior for, and in the subclass's `viewDidLoad`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(
        title: "", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
}
```

This way, you can choose which controllers you want the behavior for, without duplicating code. I prefer my controllers to just say "Back", rather than the title of the previous controller, so I set that title here.

Answer (score 8):

You can use xcode 8 and swift 3.0

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backItem?.title = " "
```

Comment: Won't this remove the title from the previous view controller altogether?

Comment: Yes, it will remove the title for all `ViewController`s pushed from `self.navigationController`

Answer (score 7):

A method for iOS13.

```
let backButtonAppearance = UIBarButtonItemAppearance(style: .plain)
backButtonAppearance.normal.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.clear]

let navigationBarAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
navigationBarAppearance.backButtonAppearance = backButtonAppearance

UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = navigationBarAppearance
```

Comment: Single solution that works for me on iOS 16.1.1

Answer (score 6):

```
let barAppearace = UIBarButtonItem.appearance()
barAppearace.setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment(UIOffsetMake(0, -60), for:UIBarMetrics.default)
```

used this line of code in swift 3.0

Comment: will affect the cancel button for UISearchController

Answer (score 5):

Taking inspiration from [rordulu's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1582255/rordulu) answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24572572/1532838), I ended up creating a custom UINavigationController and UINavigation bar which seems to handle all cases of this tricky problem.

1) Initialise new `UINavigationController` with your custom `UINavigationBar`:

```
class CustomNavigationController: UINavigationController {

    convenience init() {
        self.init(navigationBarClass: CustomNavigationBar.self, toolbarClass: nil)
    }
}
```

2) Set the `backItem.title` property of the navigation bar to an empty string, every time the view lays itself out

```
class CustomNavigationBar: UINavigationBar {

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        backItem?.title = ""
        super.layoutSubviews()
    }
}
```

Now every time you use this navigation controller and bar combination, it will never have back button text!

*Note: this should work fine if using storyboards also, just ensure to drop the custom navigation bar component into the view*

Comment: Amazing thanks so much! This is the best way to do it and should be the correct answer :)

Comment: Just realised that this has a side-effect in that it will wipe the navigation item title completely. So when the previous view shows, it will not have a title!

I will carry on my search for the perfect solution to this annoying problem.

Comment: damn you are right. How could i miss that! Please tell me if you find a fix of this issue. thanks

Comment: Could you find out the perfect solution @HarryBloom?

Comment: @Hemang Not a perfect solution, but I found something that works. Have added a second answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/49094282/1532838

Answer (score 4):

**Simple Solution :**

While you are pushing 2nd controller from 1st controller, put **self.navigationItem.title = ""** in **viewWillDisappear** of 1st controller. It hides back button title from 2nd controller.

Above statment hides 1st controllers title, hence when we came back we want title for 1st controller again. For that we have **add title** for 1st controller in **viewWillAppear** method of 1st controller.

**Refer following methods (of 1st controller)**

```
    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationItem.title = ""
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationItem.title = "Title"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Works on **Swift 5**:

```
        self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.title = ""
```

Please note it will be effective for the next pushed view controller not the current one on the display, that's why it's very confusing!

Also, check the storyboard and select the navigation item of the **previous** view controller then type something in the **Back Button** (Inspector).

Comment: title is not a get property, check Apple documentation

Answer (score 3):

I usually add or change the back button in viewDidLoad of the UIViewController.

Something like that should work:

```
let leftButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style:     UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "closeView:")
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftButton
```

Don't forget to change and implement the function that it's called to close the view.

Even easier, just change the title:

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.title = "Back"
```

Comment: This breaks iOS's built-in support for swiping left to right to navigate back, and IMHO, apps that break this are really irritating.

Answer (score 3):

```
    if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
        navigationItem.backButtonDisplayMode = .minimal
    } else {
        navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Swift 3:

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title:"", style:.plain, target:nil, action:nil)
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding a second answer here as my first only partially works. This method is less elegant in the fact that it requires calling a method in each view in the application, however it works without any side-effects.

So firstly, create a UIViewController extension class with a function to remove back button text and add a custom back button:

```
extension UIViewController {

func setBackButton() {
    navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = R.image.backArrow()
    navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = R.image.backArrow()
    navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: " ", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
}
```

Secondly, we can simply call out to this function in the `viewDidLoad` of each view controller you need it in.

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 4.2**

```
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([.foregroundColor: UIColor.clear], for: .normal)
```

Comment: Cancel and Done button of imagepicker are disappeared in this approach

Answer (score 2):

**Updated Answer For Swift 4.2**

Working with `UIAppearance` is a cleaner way of solving the problem but it would cause all the `UIBarButtonItem` to have a clear text. An improved version of the solution could be to check if the `UIBarButtonItem` is contained in a `UINavigationBar`.

```
    UIBarButtonItem.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UINavigationBar.self]).setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.clear], for: .normal)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just create extension of `UIViewController` with override function `awakeFromNib()` and make `UIBarButtonItem` with an empty title and give to `navigation backBarButtonItem`.

```
extension UIViewController {

  open override func awakeFromNib() {
    let backBarBtnItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
    navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backBarBtnItem
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

if you want to remove back button title when you open next screen

do this inside the function initialising and pushing a new screen:

```
navigationItem.backButtonTitle = ""
```

Full usage:

```
    let view = SomeView()
    let controller = UIHostingController(rootView: view)
    navigationItem.backButtonTitle = ""
    navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
```

But to customise back buttons for all navigation bars in your app you need to do this:

```
func setupNavBarAppearance() {
    let backButtonImage = Images.west.image.withAlignmentRectInsets(UIEdgeInsets(top: -5, left: -15, bottom: -5, right: -15))
    let backButtonAppearance = UIBarButtonItemAppearance(style: .plain)
    backButtonAppearance.normal.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.clear]
    
    let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
    appearance.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.white]
    appearance.backButtonAppearance = backButtonAppearance
    appearance.setBackIndicatorImage(backButtonImage, transitionMaskImage: backButtonImage)
    
    UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = appearance
    UINavigationBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = .white
    UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
}
```

You can call it from your AppDelegate.swift

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4.2 & 5**

Instead of playing with the navigation bar tint color which will have side effects if you are using image picker anytime later in your code.

Use below code:

```
extension UIViewController {
        open override func awakeFromNib() {
            navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
    }  
}
```

Call it from your first ViewController:

```
self.awakeFromNib()
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the below code in any of the `UIViewcontroller extension` it will hide all the `UIViewcontroller` back text

```
open override func awakeFromNib() {
        navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a simple solution for those, who don't want to use method swizzling or duplicating a similar code in different view controllers.

To remove back button title, create a UINavigationController subclass and override pushViewController(_, animated:) method:

```
final class CustomNavigationController: UINavigationController {

    override func pushViewController(_ viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {

        super.pushViewController(viewController, animated: animated)

        let backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem()
        backBarButtonItem.title = nil

        viewController.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backBarButtonItem
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but I found problem with hiding back button title in iPhone pluses but in device without plus shows correct with

```
leftBarButtonItem.title = ""
```

So I found simple way. It is set tint color to clear in NavigationBar of NavigationViewController in autolayout. It may be problem if you use icons or text tiles with tint. But in my case I don't use it as all.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this:

```
func removeBackButton(vc:UIViewController) {
        let button = UIButton.init(type: .custom)
        button.setImage(UIImage.init(named:""), for: .normal)
        let leftBarButton = UIBarButtonItem.init(customView: button)
        vc.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftBarButton
}
```

So call this method in viewDidLoad:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
     removeBackButton(vc:self)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add this extension to UIViewController
And then call this function in every viewDidLoad()
like : self.updateBackButton()

```
extension UIViewController {
func updateBackButton(){
    if self.navigationController != nil {
        self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .done, target: self, action: nil)
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to share a solution that works for me. Also, it can be adjusted base on your needs and requirements.

Note, in my case, I use a storyboard to specify CustomNavigationBar

Swift 4.2

```
class CustomNavigationBar: UINavigationBar {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        guard let topItem = topItem else { return }
        removeBackButtonTitle(for: topItem)
    }

    override func pushItem(_ item: UINavigationItem, animated: Bool) {
        removeBackButtonTitle(for: item)
        super.pushItem(item, animated: animated)
    }

    func removeBackButtonTitle(for item: UINavigationItem) {
        item.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Works for **Swift 4.2**

Using the line of code in `AppDelegate` file into `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
    UIBarButtonItem.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UINavigationBar.self]).setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.clear], for: .normal)

    UIBarButtonItem.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UINavigationBar.self]).setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.clear], for: .highlighted)
```

Comment: This hides the back bar button text but unfortunately doesn't center the navigation bar title

Answer (score 0):

for swift 4,5

```
let BarButtonItemAppearance = UIBarButtonItem.appearance()
BarButtonItemAppearance.setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.clear], for: .normal)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class NavigationController: UINavigationController {

    override func pushViewController(_ viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        super.pushViewController(viewController, animated: animated)

        viewController.navigationItem.backButtonTitle = ""
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
final class MainNavigationController: UINavigationController {
    override init(rootViewController: UIViewController) {
        super.init(rootViewController: rootViewController)
        delegate = self
    }

    @available(*, unavailable)
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

// MARK: UINavigationController Delegate
extension MainNavigationController: UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    func navigationController(
        _ navigationController: UINavigationController,
        willShow viewController: UIViewController,
        animated: Bool
    ) {
        viewController.navigationItem.backButtonTitle = ""
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very important that before pushing viewController you set back title to an empty string:

```
let myNextViewContorller = UIViewController()
navigationItem.backButtonTitle = ""
navigationController.push(myNextViewContorller, animated: true)
```

Answer (score -1):

in `viewDidLoad()`

```
    let backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: nil, style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
    navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backBarButtonItem
```

Answer (score -4):

I was not satisfied with the `setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment` solution, so here is a swift alternative to hide all back button texts throughout the applicataion:

```
    UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: barbuttonFont, NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.clearColor()], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: barbuttonFont, NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.clearColor()], forState: UIControlState.Highlighted)
```

You would have to call these from the `AppDelegate` in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` func.

Appearance must be set to the `.Highlighted` state too to avoid texts being show when the user taps the back button.

Comment: that will hide all other UIBarButtonItems as well