# Swift - Remove a title from backBarButtonItem, but keep the arrow

Tags: ios, swift

How can I remove a title from back button in navigation bar, but I want to keep the arrow.

Comment: refer this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/48801613/3976183

Answer (score 8):

Set the title text to an empty string.

```
navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .Plain, target: nil, action: nil)
```

*Edit:*
As per comments below this will only work if you set the back button before you segue to the view controller with the button in it.

Comment: Note - you have to apply it to previous VC, not to current

Comment: @markov What do you mean by that?

Comment: You'll need to set it before you segue to the destinationViewController. You'll probably want to do it in prepareForSegue on the VC originating the segue.

Answer (score 3):

If you do not need the title, do this in `viewDidLoad` of your previous `ViewController`

```
title = ""
```

If you need the `title` for first `ViewController`, toggle `setTitle` between `viewWillAppear` and `viewWillDisAppear` of previous `viewController` will do.