# UINavigationController Back button doesn't hide title on iOS 11

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationitem, ios11

I've updated my device to iOS 11 Beta yesterday and my app using this code in AppDelegate for hide back button title on all screen:

```
@implementation UINavigationItem (Customization)

/**
 Removes text from all default back buttons so only the arrow or custom image shows up.
 */
-(UIBarButtonItem *)backBarButtonItem
{
    return [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
}
```

It's working normally on older version but when I run my app on iOS 11 Beta, the title of back button still shown.
Does anyone face this problem? Is it a beta version bug of iOS or iOS 11 need another way to hide the back button title?

Comment: working in iOS11: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33025959/7084910

Comment: @Patel unfortunately this doesn't work in iOS11

Answer (score 6):

I've been using your approach previously, but unfortunately it's not working any more. After trying all possible solutions, that's the only thing that I found working without any issues and bugs. Please note, that it seems that there's no more a universal way to fix this globally for all UIViewControllers.

1. Call

   ```
   self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"" style:self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.style target:nil action:nil];
   ```

on `viewWillDisappear` of the presenting controller.

2. Call

   ```
   self.title = @"Title"
   ```

on `viewWillAppear` of the presenting controller.

Other solutions that I have tried have various issues, e.g. they are working fine but everything breaks when you swipe from left edge a bit.

Comment: Yeah, I though iOS 11 need a different way to hide back button title. So I was remove my old code then used custom button instead. At this time, it's working without any issues and bugs too.

Comment: Thank you for this solution. This is the only solution that works in iOS 11. iOS 11 broke so many things in our app.

Comment: Make sure you do this on the viewController it's referring to from the back button, not the one you're segueing into.

Answer (score 2):

What I did in iOS 11 was simply to implement the `UINavigationControllerDelegate` protocol for my root navigation controllers and to set the "blank" UIBarButtonItem as back button everytime a new controller will be displayed. Here is the Swift 4 version:

```
func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, willShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
    viewController.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the bar button title text color to clear is the cleanest way I've found to apply for all screens

```
 UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.clear], for: .normal)
 UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.clear], for: .highlighted)
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try next time.

Answer (score 0):

### FOR SWIFT 3+

Use below code to support iOS 9 to 11

```
     if #available(iOS 11, *) {
            UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.clear], for: .normal)
            UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.clear], for: .highlighted)
     } else {
            UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment(UIOffsetMake(0,
-60), for:UIBarMetrics.default)
        }
```

Comment: This sets all bar button items to clear, probably not what most people are looking for