# Show "Cancel" button in photo gallery (UIImagePickerController) swift 4

Tags: iphone, swift, swift4, xcode9

In my **AppDelegate.swift** file I have this two lines:

```
let barButtonItemMenu = UIBarButtonItem.appearance()   
     barButtonItemMenu.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.clear], for: .normal)
```

that allows me to remove the `back` text in my all navigation controllers. All is good but when I open the photo gallery with `UIImagePickerController` the `Cancel` button does not appear, but when I delete that two lines the `Cancel` button appears and my `back` text appears.

My question is how can I show the `Cancel` button in my photo gallery? and how can I remove the `back` text in my all navigation controllers?

Comment: Where are you writing these lines ? in didLoad of every controller ?

Comment: @iOSGeek I am writing that in my AppDelegate.swift in my didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method

Comment: Is this query Solved ?

Answer (score 2):

Basically you are clearing text of navigation controller button

You can try doing one thing instead of clearing text of back button using

```
let barButtonItemMenu = UIBarButtonItem.appearance()   
     barButtonItemMenu.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.clear], for: .normal)
```

**Make use of**

```
self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: false)
```

This will not clear your text as you doing but will hide the button in navigation stack

You can just use this simple line in WillAppear to make that button hide

ScreenShot 1 - After navigating to VC1 from other Vc which do not show Back Button as Required - **Expected Output**

[image]

ScreenShot 2 -  When Clicked on Button at centre of VC1 library is presented using imagePicker which having cancel button as shown - **Expected Output**

[image]

Have A look at demo project - https://drive.google.com/open?id=1exKMgZSQZ8zT64yJOh-MX5O-uAIPdrj6

Comment: Welcome, Happy Coding

Answer (score 0):

This is not correct way to remove back button text. You are actually changing the color of button to clear which makes it invisible but button remains there and it is still interact able. Correct way to remove back button text is [remove back button text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33025239/ios-remove-text-from-back-button-keeping-the-icon)

And when you’ll do this, your image picker controller will also have cancel button