# Remove title or text for back button in iOS app for entire app

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

In my entire iOS app, I want to show custom back button in navigation bar with out text. 
Here's my code:

```
let navBarAppearance = UINavigationBar.appearance()
navBarAppearance.backIndicatorImage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "back")
navBarAppearance.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "back")
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment(UIOffsetMake(0, -60), for: .default)
```

But when I'm running the code, its throwing warnings related to layout for my last line of code. How can I have custom back button without text and without getting any warnings during compile & run time?

Answer (score 0):

You can delete text of back button for whole app with writing this code inside AppDelegate;

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    //Delete Text of Back Button
    let BarButtonItemAppearance = UIBarButtonItem.appearance()
    BarButtonItemAppearance.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.clear], for: .normal)

    return true
}
```

For more answers, please check below post;

[Remove text from Back button keeping the icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33025239/remove-text-from-back-button-keeping-the-icon?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: Bad approach. That will clear the text color of all bar buttons. Also since the text is still there it will take touches.

Comment: if you copy and paste the answer please add the ref : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23853617/uinavigationbar-hide-back-button-text of copy

Comment: @Anbu.karthik I added different reference which yurs doesn't have my answer.

Comment: @HAK Sorry I couldn't find better approach for this question. What would you suggest? Can you please write ur answer?