# Remove the text from back button in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, ios13, ios-navigationview

In short, I want to [do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33025239/remove-text-from-back-button-keeping-the-icon), but with SwiftUI.

[image]

(**Home** should be removed)

So far, I have not found a way to access the `NavigationBarButton` directly, and have managed to find the following that appears to be the only way I can find to date for modifying the button:

```
struct MyList: View {
    var body: some View {
            Text("MyList")
            .navigationBarTitle(Text(verbatim: "MyList"), displayMode: .inline)
            .navigationBarItems(leading: Text("<"))
    }
}
```

However, I lose the default return image and get an ugly < instead.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to set the title of the view that the back button will pop to:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: DetailView()) {
                    Text("push view")
                }
            }.navigationBarTitle("", displayMode: .inline)
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Detail View")
    }
}
```

Alternatively, to conditionally set or unset the title of the source view, depending on the presentation status you can use the code below.

Beware that the isActive parameter has a bug, but that will most likely be solved soon. Here's a reference to the bug mentioned [SwiftUI: NavigationDestinationLink deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57273717/swiftui-navigationdestinationlink-deprecated)

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var active: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(), isActive: $active) {
                    Text("push view")
                }
            }.navigationBarTitle(!active ? "View Title" : "", displayMode: .inline)
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Detail View")
    }
}
```

Comment: While this solves the immediate problem, it creates a new one. Now the "source" view controller has no title in the navigation bar.

Comment: Added another alternative.

Comment: Thanks @kontiki, this works perfectly, with the exception of the bug you noted.

Comment: doesn't work in 2021.  ..."displayMode: .inline" doesn't work, and adding navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline) on a separate line doesn't work.

Comment: I found this worked for me, provided I 1) removed the `!` from `!active`, 2) changed the call to `navigationBarTitle()` to `navigationTitle()`, and 3) put the `.inline` specification in its own line of code as in `.navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)`

Answer (score 3):

Instead of messing with the previous screen's title, you can simply add a 'principal' item in the navigation bar, and make it take up so much space that there is no room for the back button text. SwiftUI will automatically continue showing the back button, but hide its text:

```
.toolbar {
  ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) { Color.clear }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking to work with **iOS 16 NavigationStack** and need to hide the back button title, you can achieve this with a straightforward solution by setting the `toolbarRole` to `editor`.

```
.toolbarRole(.editor)
```

For Example:

```
struct SecondView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello Second View")
            .navigationTitle("Second View")
            .toolbarRole(.editor)
    }
}
```

And the output will be like below:

[image: Hide Back Button]

Answer (score 0):

SwiftUI's toolbar modifier is much more flexible than the navigationBar modifiers. You aren't limited to a string or Text view as a parameter. Use the built-in environment action *dismiss* instead of the back button. Dynamic capability and works like a charm.

```
struct MyList: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World!")
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                    Button {
                        dismiss()
                    } label: {
                        Text("<")
                    }
                }
                ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
                    Text("MyList")
                }
            }
            .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Works on iOS 16

`Since you can update NavigationItem inside the init of the View. You can solve this in 2 steps:`

1. Get visible View Controller.

```
// Get Visible ViewController
extension UIApplication {
    
    static var visibleVC: UIViewController? {
        var currentVC = UIApplication.shared.windows.first { $0.isKeyWindow }?.rootViewController
        while let presentedVC = currentVC?.presentedViewController {
            if let navVC = (presentedVC as? UINavigationController)?.viewControllers.last {
                currentVC = navVC
            } else if let tabVC = (presentedVC as? UITabBarController)?.selectedViewController {
                currentVC = tabVC
            } else {
                currentVC = presentedVC
            }
        }
        return currentVC
    }
    
}
```

2. Update NavigationItem inside init of the View.

```
struct YourView: View {
    
    init(hideBackLabel: Bool = true) {
        if hideBackLabel {
            // iOS 14+
            UIApplication.visibleVC?.navigationItem.backButtonDisplayMode = .minimal
            
            // iOS 13-
            let button = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
            UIApplication.visibleVC?.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = button
        }
    }

}
```