# Default text for back button in NavigationView in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui

I use a `NavigationLink` to navigate from "View1" to "View2", on the second view, the back button gets the title of the previous view

[image]

But, if the title of the previous view is very long, then the back button gets the text "Back"

[image]

How could I change that "Back" text?

I wanna make my app available in multiple languages, but it seems that "Back" does not change when phone's language changes

```
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {

        return NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Text("View1")
                NavigationLink(destination: Text("View2").navigationBarTitle("Title View2", displayMode: .inline)) {
                    Text("NavigationLink")
                }
            }.navigationBarTitle("Title View1")
        }

    }
}
```

PS: I'd like to keep this functionality as it it, I just want to change the language used for back button

Comment: use your custom bar button

Comment: refer to the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57378744/remove-the-text-from-back-button-in-swiftui

Comment: I observed that if application has localizable resources then default *Back* string is translated to current iOS language set in **Settings** (ie. one of supported), but this cannot be overridden (at first I coincidentally translated *Back* string in the same way as system does and thought that in this way it would be possible to substitute *Back*, but nope).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've managed to localize back buttons by providing translations for the `Back` key in the `Localizable.strings` file.

I am using SwiftUI though.

Comment: Did you simply added something like `"Back" = "Назад";` in your `Localizable.strings` file? I just did like that, but it's not working for me, although all other strings localizes as expected.

Comment: @ViestursKnopkens Yep that worked for me. Make sure that you are setting the locale for your `NavigationView` and not to the contained View

Comment: I'm setting it with `NavigationView { ... }.environment(\.locale, .init(identifier: "ru"))`. Maybe I'm doing it wrong?

Comment: @ViestursKnopkens I'm getting the same issue, did you find out any solution for this?

Comment: Unfortunately no. Although I'm not sure if it's not fixed by now, because recently I haven't done projects which require localization, for that project we just left it like that – "Back" in all languages. Sorry, I can't say anything promising :)

Answer (score 9):

here is a workaround ....

```
struct ContentView: View {
        @State private var isActive: Bool = false

        var body: some View {
            NavigationView {
                VStack {
                    NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(), isActive: $isActive) {
                        Text("Title View2")
                    }
                }.navigationBarTitle(! isActive ? "Title View2" : "Your desired back Title", displayMode: .inline)
            }
        }
    }

    struct DetailView: View {
        var body: some View {
            Text("View2")
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm using SwiftUI, sorry I forgot to mention

Comment: This approach is glitchy, unfortunately. When navigating back, the shortened title appears momentarily before switching to the full title.

Answer (score 6):

You can create a custom back button in your navigation link by hiding native navigationBackButton.  In the custom back button, you can add your translated custom back button title.

```
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {

        return NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Text("View1")
                NavigationLink("NavigationLink", destination: NextView())
            }.navigationBarTitle("Title View1")
        }
    }
}
struct NextView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>

    var backButton : some View { Button(action: {
        self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        }) {
            HStack {
            Image("backImage") // BackButton Image
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                Text("Go Back") //translated Back button title 
            }
        }
    }
    var body: some View {
            VStack {
            Text("View2")
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Title View2",displayMode: .inline)
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
        .navigationBarItems(leading: backButton)
    }
}
```

Output:-

[image]

Comment: by doing this you lose an interactive swipe gesture. not cool

Answer (score 5):

I found a solution which can work also very good.

View1 set a toolbar item with .principal and add your Text or what you want.

for example :

```
ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
    HStack{
        Text("View1")
    }.font(.subheadline)
}
```

and set also your title in View1:

```
.navigationTitle("Back")
```

And do nothing in your view2. it will automatically add your view1 title to your view2 default back button text

Comment: The principal ToolbarItem is a great suggestion, it will work as the default navigation button, but the navigation view doesn't know about the actual title so it has to just show the back button. Although if you want it to match other default titles, the font should be `.headline`, not `.subheadline`.

Comment: This worked better for me than the selected answer, because my base view with the navigation bar was not doing the presentation (a subview was).

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't hide the native back button as that would disable things like the [back to swipe gesture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59921239/hide-navigation-bar-without-losing-swipe-back-gesture-in-swiftui), or tap-and-hold to select a page.

A better alternative is [hiding the back button text](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76780763/35690), and then adding a custom button, in the child screen:

```
    .toolbar {
      ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) { Color.clear }
      ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarLeading) {
        Button("Back 2") { dismiss() }.offset(x: -25)
      }
    }
```

[image]

However, if the user tries to tap-and-hold on the new button they won't be able to select a page. Additionally, the `-25` is not ideal. Therefore you might be better off with a solution that changes the previous screen's text.

---

In case you're wondering, it doesn't appear that the `ToolbarItem` APIs (on the child page) can replace the back button icon/text. Even if you add every single placement, you'll notice that the original back button is intact:

```
    .toolbar {
      // `Group` used due to 10 limit on views

      // leading
      Group {
        ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarLeading) { Text("L") }
        ToolbarItem(placement: .cancellationAction) { Text("X") }
      }

      // center
      Group {
        ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) { Text("P") }
      }

      // trailing
      Group {
        ToolbarItem(placement: .automatic) { Text("A") }
        ToolbarItem(placement: .navigation) { Text("N") }
        ToolbarItem(placement: .primaryAction) { Text("1") }
        ToolbarItem(placement: .confirmationAction) { Text("C") } // shows in bold
        ToolbarItem(placement: .destructiveAction) { Text("D") }
        ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarTrailing) { Text("T") }
      }

      // trailing but shows "ellipsis.circle" instead
      Group {
        ToolbarItem(placement: .secondaryAction) { Text("2") }
        ToolbarItem(placement: .status) { Text("S") }
      }

      // doesn't appear on the top
      Group {
        ToolbarItem(placement: .keyboard) { Text("K") }
        ToolbarItem(placement: .bottomBar) { Text("B") }
      }
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Create your own button, then assign it using .navigationBarItems(). I found the following format most nearly approximated the default back button.

```
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>

    var backButton : some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        }) {
            HStack(spacing: 0) {
                Image(systemName: "chevron.left")
                    .font(.title2)
                Text("Cancel")
            }
        }
    }
```

Make sure you use `.navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)` to hide the default button and replace it with your own!

```
        List(series, id:\.self, selection: $selection) { series in
            Text(series.SeriesLabel)
        }
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
        .navigationBarItems(leading: backButton)
```

Comment: However, this will break the swipe to go back gesture, which is very important for accessibility and usability.

Answer (score 0):

Tested this on Xcode 15.3 and iOS 17.0

Just add a toolbar leading button with clear color and it should force show `Back` as title for navbar.

```
.navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            .navigationTitle(navigationTitle)
            .toolbar {
                // Hack: To show back title for navigation bar
                ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarLeading) {
                    Button { } label: {
                        Color.clear
                    }

                }
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

Add localization to your project. If language was set with user device settings(or simulator), after you add localization to your project it will work.  Project's supported language must match with selected one on device.