# iOS Swift - How to remove top bar back button's "Back" text?

Tags: ios, swift

I tried to identify what the "Back" text is from by the following:

```
  public override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setTransparent(style: .default)
    print(self.navigationItem.backButtonTitle)
    print(self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.title)
    print(self.navigationItem.title)
    print(self.navigationItem.titleView?.largeContentTitle)
  }
```

However I got all nil outputs, which means these titles are not there:

nil
nil
nil
nil

I also tried this:

```
self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: false)
```

It works but it hides the whole thing, including the back arrow "<" and the text "Back". I wanted to keep the arrow but only remove the text.

Where can I find this title or text that says "Back" and set it to empty string?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove text from Back button keeping the icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33025239/remove-text-from-back-button-keeping-the-icon)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work for you

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = " "
```

Comment: Apple will say this is cheating cheating.....

Answer (score 0):

one way is shown in attached Image.

Second one is follow:

```
navigationItem.backButtonTitle = ""
```

[image]

Comment: print(navigationItem.backButtonTitle) is actually nil, and setting it to nil or empty string doesn't do anything.

Comment: Please use this method, may be it solve your problem,


func setBackItem() {
        let backItem = UIBarButtonItem()
        backItem.title = AppConstants.empty
        navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backItem
        navigationItem.backButtonTitle = AppConstants.empty

    }

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom left bar button item, in viewDidLoad:

```
let myimage = UIImage(systemName: "chevron.backward")
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: myimage, style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleBack))
```

to go back the button call handleBack func:

```
@objc fileprivate func handleBack() {
    navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```