# Set all back buttons like leftBarButtonItem with custom image

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

How do I set a custom image to all back buttons of view controllers pushed in a UINavigationController?

My issues are:

- must look like `leftBarButtonItem`, position-wise (because the `backBarButtonItem` itself is too glued to the left and I can't seem to change it's horizontal alignment).
- has to be on all back actions (instead of manually setting on each view controller).
- having a method `setCustomBackButton` and calling it on each view controller is also not an option, I'm looking for something like `UINavigationBar.appearance()`, i.e., throughout the app.

Something like this:
[image]
But with the back action working without me manually setting the selector on each view controller.

UPDATE: In response to Joe's solution, I'm getting that error:
[image]

Comment: check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43546132/how-to-customize-the-navigation-back-symbol-and-navigation-back-text/43556837#43556837

Comment: @Joe that's exactly what I wanted to avoid, setting it on every view controller.

Answer (score 4):

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().backIndicatorImage = UIImage(named: "backArrow")
```

See Here: https://www.raywenderlich.com/108766/uiappearance-tutorial

Comment: Tried it, the text from the previous view controller will still be there.

Comment: Actually I just tried again and it doesn't even change anything.

Comment: You didn't mention you also wanted to hide the back button title, which is an entirely different matter. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19078995/removing-the-title-text-of-an-ios-uibarbuttonitem

Comment: Also, where are you setting `backIndicatorImage`? I'd say `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` would be the best option to make sure it gets applied to every navigation bar

Comment: Well, I did upload an image to show what I wanted =), but still, I also tried that hack and it doesn't work, the title from the current view controller is pushed to the right, because the title from the previous controller is still there (even though it's pushed to the left).

Comment: We cannot see if the previous view controller had a title or not :P In any case, would the following work for you: 'If you use Storyboard, you can set navigation attributes inspector Back Button with space'? Make sure you use a space and not leave the 'back button' field empty, otherwise it will default to 'Back'. Unfortunately, you would need to do that for each view controller (note that you need to d&d a `Navigation Item` into a view controller scene first).

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I wanted to avoid, doing it for every view controller.

Answer (score 1):

Below answer based on the following `OP` answers:

[Custom Back Button With Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26936296/custom-back-button-with-image) and [How to remove all navigationbar back button title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29912489/how-to-remove-all-navigationbar-back-button-title/33707584#33707584)

Try below code in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method in `AppDelegate`.

**To setting up a custom back button:**

```
    let backArrowImage  = UIImage(named: "back") // set your back button image here
    let renderedImage = backArrowImage?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
    UINavigationBar.appearance().backIndicatorImage = renderedImage
    UINavigationBar.appearance().backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = renderedImage
```

**To hide a back button title:**

```
    let barAppearace = UIBarButtonItem.appearance()
    barAppearace.setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment(UIOffsetMake(0, -60), for:UIBarMetrics.default)
```

**Output:** **`Updated`**

[image]

**Update:**

You need to add the following code to your `More Information` viewController to keep the `title position`.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
}
```

Comment: This is very close to what I need, but I still need to move the image a little to the right, just like on the `leftBarButtonItem`, which is the first bullet point of my question.

Comment: Actually in one case I still get the title alignment error. I'll add the image to the question

Comment: And in fact, it seems to happen when the title text is not big enough.

Comment: can't replicate the error. its works ok on iPhone 5 sim.even it works, if the mainVC title longer than normal in length or shorter.

Comment: Try setting the title of the previous view controller to be big as in "More information" and run on iPhone 5 simulator. So instead of "Main VC" write "More information".

Comment: That updated code forces me to set it up on every view controller, which is exactly what I wanted to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own subclass of `UINavigationController` and change the button inside the `navigationController(_:willShow:animated:)` delegate method as follows:

```
class MyNavigationController: UINavigationController, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        delegate = self
        interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = self
    }

    func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, willShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        if viewController != self.viewControllers.first { // don't add button to rootViewController
            let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "backArrow"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(popViewController(animated:)) )
            viewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton
        }
    }

}
```

Theoretically the above delegate method could live anywhere, but this way its logical and easy to select where you want to have this functionality.

Also don't forget to set the `interactivePopGestureRecognizer` delegate for not loosing the edge swipe gesture to go back (this somehow breaks when setting a new leftBarButtonItem).

The above method could be further improved by keeping track of which view controllers were already shown and then only replace the leftBarButtonItem on new ones (right now it also replaces it when going back/popping to an already shown view controller).

Answer (score 0):

Try this  Swift 4.2

```
extension YouFirstViewController: UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, willShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        if !(viewController is YouFirstViewController) {
            let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "icnBack"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(popview))
            viewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton
        }
    }

    @objc func popview() {
        navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }

}
```

onYouFirstViewController

```
class YouFirstViewController: UIViewcontroller {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.navigationController?.delegate = self
    }
}
```